# OpenMP parallel for with boost:: directory_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, openmp

I have a code + error message above, and I can't get to solve the problem. Any ideas?

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
#pragma omp for
        for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(p_c); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
        {
            std::string outputfile = (out_p/itr->path().filename()).string();
            cv::Mat image = cv::imread(itr->path().string());
            ImageContainer imgc = ImageContainer(itr->path().string(), outputfile, image);
            if(!imgc.Image().data)
            {
                std::cout << imgc.Input_Path() << " is not found." << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << "Processing " << imgc.Input_Path() << std::endl;
            streaks_detection(imgc);
        }
```

The error message about the **initalization** of **directory_iterator** in the head of for.

```
.../main.cpp:248: error: parenthesized initialization is not allowed in OpenMP 'for' loop
         for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(p_c); itr != end_itr; ++itr)


                                    ^
```

Comment: Why not simply writing `itr = p_c` then?

Comment: did you try already `boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr = p_c;...` ?

Comment: yes, then the error is :
`error: conversion from 'boost::filesystem::path' to non-scalar type 'boost::filesystem::directory_iterator' requested
         for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr = p_c; itr != end_itr; ++itr)`

Comment: @koviroli What is `p_c` actually? Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: can you put `boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(p_c);` before the loop and then write the loops as `for ( ; itr < ...` ?

Comment: @user9212993 `p_c` is a `boost::filesystem::path`.

@tobi303 the error message without first part of `for` `expected iteration declaration`

Comment: @koviroli Please put all additional information into your question. It's not very helpful, for others, if they have to go through the comments to get all necessary info. Best as mentioned above you provide a [MCVE] that everyone is able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @user9212993 you are right, thanks for advice, i will edit my question in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly use a `directory_iterator` in a worksharing loop, because it is not a random access iterator. The easiest way around that is to just `std::copy` to a `st::vector`, and then do the parallel loop over the vector. Alternatively you can use locks and manual worksharing, but that more difficult to get right.